# I cannot connect to the internet via ethernet

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint

I have been previously running Windows 8 on my Toshiba and of recent I decided to make a multiboot with Linux Mint Olivia 15.

When I start the machine on Windows, I can access internet with an Ethernet cable plugged into my pc, but when i start the machine on Linux, I cannot access internet using an Ethernet cable. I configured the proxies of the network am using correctly in my browser. Can anyone help me on this?

NB: Am running a dual boot of Windows where Windows was pre-installed and I created a partition for installing Linux Mint.
I tried to ping the default gateway and am successful except that I cannot ping external sites.
My network adapters are **broadcom 802.11n wireless adapter and Realtek PCIe Fe family Ethernet controller** respectivley

Comment: Did you install the correct network adapter drivers in Linux? Can you ping any addresses (like, say, your router)?   What's your current networking setup in Linux?

Comment: This sounds like a simply driver issue.  Specific information on your network adapter is required to do research.

Comment: Do you know how your machine gets its IP in Windows? Maybe DHCP? Is it configured like this for Mint as well?

Comment: If you can give us the model of your Toshiba, or even better the exact model of your Network Interface Card, people can research how to set up and configure it under your version of Mint.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping to your router, if there is no response your configuration is not ok, try to take a look running `ifconfig` and see if router give you DHCP configuration or not, and don't forget to look at `/etc/resolv.conf`

Usefull comands:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 # try to get a response from router
```

if response is ok, try to modify /etc/resolv.conf file like this:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/resolv.conf
>nameserver 8.8.8.8
>nameserver 8.8.4.4
>EOF
```

and last, take a look into /etc/network/interfaces

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

see if eth0 is present or if it has static configuration and set it to dhcp or something.

I hope this would help you.